# if-else statement nested in while-loops

Tags: javascript, if-statement, while-loop

I am a beginner when it comes to Javascript. I am not really sure where to ask appropriately and I thought since I've been stalking Stack Overflow for awhile now, this might be the right time to finally make an account and start my profile here. The book I am reading doesn't really have a Help Forum of any sort.

Anyways, I am reading a book that is in tandem with some JS exercise and I wanted to try combining principles of *while-loops* that contain nested *if..else statements*. My code is below :

```
var teams = ["Chiefs", "Bees", "Tigers", "Bears"];
var i = 0;
while (i < teams.length) {
  if (teams[i] === "Lions") {
    alert(teams[i] + " is at Index " + i + " in the array");
    break;
  } else {
    alert("Query not found!");
    break;
  }
  i++;
}
```

The exercise was only suppose to be using the concept of *while* and *if* but obviously with my curiosity into programming I wanted to add the *else* statement but I cannot get the code to work. The only instance I got the code to work properly was without the *else* statement.

My main goal/curiosity is I would like it to alert "Query not found!" when the if statement can't find the string in the array, in this case I've written "Lions".

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Remove the break from the else.

Comment: oh im sorry! I forgot to change the teams[i] === "Tigers" to something else that isn't in the array. That is what I was after, for the else alert to show when it can't find a string in the teams array!

Comment: Remove the `break` statements from both your `if` and your `else` controls and you will get the "Query not found!" alert for each item in the `teams` array that is NOT "Tigers".

Comment: It doesn't work that way. 'else' will execute whenever 'if' doesn't match.

Comment: You could set a flag in the if and then test for it after the loop completes.

Comment: @bwegs if I removed the breaks it alerts four times..and even if a match in the array happens, it would alert positively ("Tigers is at...") then followed by a "Query not found!"

Comment: Break in the 'if' is fine. It makes it more efficient, if you just want to drop out as soon as you've found your match. You just need a way to check if 'if' executed after loop.

Comment: The exact results you're expecting aren't clear, what are you expecting to happen?

Comment: Remove break in else, set flag in if, check flag after loop. This will solve your problem. Sorry can't write code on mobile.

Comment: Also read up on if/else. It doesn't work the way you think it does.

Comment: @bwegs I would like it to alert "Query not found!" when the if statement can't find the string in the array.

Comment: See @amadan's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can decide whether something is found when you find it. But you can only decide something is not found when you've looked at everything, which should be outside the loop.

```
var teams = ["Chiefs", "Bees", "Tigers", "Bears"];
var i = 0, position = null;
while (i < teams.length) {
  if (teams[i] === "Lions") {
    position = i;
    break;
  }
  i++;
}
if (position !== null) {
  alert(teams[position] + " is at Index " + position + " in the array");
} else {
  alert("Query not found!");
}
```

Comment: This seems to work! I guess my understanding of if..else and while loops is still very fundamental as that 'position' command is new to me. I thought I would be able to make it work just using simple syntax of while..if-else loops..but then again, that code above must already be simple itself...Thank you!

Comment: `position` is not a command, just a variable I use to keep track where we found the stuff we're looking for. I did not use any new syntax: your logic was off, not the language itself.

Comment: that's what I mean! my understanding/logic is still very fundamental. I did not even know that variables can be declared next to each other (i thought there needs to always be a var declaration each line) like:
`var i = 0;
var position = null;`
that's what I'm guessing
`var i = 0, position = null;`
means?
and the `null` declaration is also new to me..
Im sorry if this comment's format is garbled..I'm reading on how to use proper markdowns right now..

Lovin' this community already!
Thank you!

Comment: Yes, `var i = 0, position = null;` is equivalent to `var i = 0; var position = null;`. [`null`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/null) is a special value that basically means "no applicable value".

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the 'break;' from the else loop. That break is going to terminate your while loop on the first iteration (when i is 0) when it doesn't find "Tigers".

break's apply to looping constructs, not if/elses. I'm guessing you thought it would break/end the else block, but its actually breaking out of the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

No need for breaks, but you can still leave one in the `if` to end the loop:

[Working Example](https://jsbin.com/lusifes/3/edit?js,console)

```
 var teams = ["Chiefs", "Bees", "Tigers", "Bears"];
 var i = 0;
 while (i < teams.length) {
  if (teams[i] === "Tigers") {
    alert(teams[i] + " is at Index " + i + " in the array");
    // can still put a break here to stop looping if you want.
  } else {
    if (i === teams.length - 1) {
      alert("Query not found!");
    }
  }
  i++;
}
```

Comment: Two problems: As a matter of style, it is not great to have the termination condition in two places (DRY); and your `i == teams.length` will never evaluate to true, as you assert in the `while` that you will only loop while `i < teams.length`, and you don't change `i` between the two conditions. Moving the `i++` above the inner `if` (or writing `if (++i === teams.length)` would fix the latter problem.